# How many numbers between $0$ and $1,000,000$ have exactly one digit equal to $9$ and the sum of digits equal $13$?

Tags: combinations

How many numbers between $0$ and $1,000,000$ have exactly one digit equal to $9$ and the sum of digits equal $13$?

I am not sure how to start this problem to get this answer. Could someone help me with this problem?

Comment: Hint: partitions of four are `{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 2}, {2, 2}, {1, 3}, {4}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to count is the number of sequences of digits of length $6$ in which the sum of digits is $13$ and there is exactly one $9$.

There are $6$ places where we can put the $9$. Once you have placed the $9$ how many options are there for the other positions? We just have to make sure that the sum of the numbers in the five positions is $4$.

Since $4$ is less than $10$ we can solve it easily with stars and bars, there are $5$ digit positions and they add up to $4$, so it is $\binom{4+5-1}{4}$.
So the final answer is $6\binom{5+4-1}{4}=6\binom{8}{4}=420$

Comment: If I understand your argument, you are choosing one of the six digits to be $9$, then calculating the number of ways that the sum of the other five digits can add to $6$.  Your first paragraph does not make this clear.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly it, let my try to fix it.

Comment: Is it better now?

Comment: Not quite.  Since there are six digits, there are six places we can put the $9$, so your original answer was correct.  You need to fix the second paragraph so that the answer you had makes sense.

Comment: Now it is clear.

Answer (score 4):

If one digit is $9$ and the sum is $13$, the other digits add up to $4$.  Not too many possibilities to consider.